# RegEx Errors Not Displaying

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

I have several text boxes in a row on a table and I'm not able to see the error message due to this, at present only a star (*) is displaying which isn't helpful to the end user.

Any ideas/solutions/fixes for this problem?

Below is my aspx code:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server" Text='<%#bind("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="FieldValidator" runat="server" 
ControlToValidate="name" ValidationGroup="vg" SetFocusOnError="True">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="name" 
ErrorMessage="* Required, no more than 20 characters allowed." ValidationGroup="vg" 
ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,20}$">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: Why you added `''-'` inside the character class?

Comment: You only have a "*" in between the `>*<` open and close tags on each validator. Change that to your message.

Comment: So the errormessage attribute isn't meant to show anything for clarity? Is there a way to access that attribute value when hovering over the textbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a Validation Summary on the page and that will display the error message. Don't put it between them instead of * as it'll set the boxes miles apart with blank space until the error is called.

Source:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator_properties(v=vs.110).aspx

Here's some code I just tested on Chrome put into an alert box so that the user can't miss it and you don't have to fiddle with whatever you're working on to accommodate for the summary:

```
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server"
            ErrorMessage="You may only enter a maxium of twenty characters."
            ControlToValidate="txtBx2"
            ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{0,20}$" Display="None"/>

<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="true" ShowSummary="false"/>
```